# Unable to send transactions from GUI wallet & Ledger [hid_error]

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, ledger, transaction-failed

I am unable to send any transactions from my Ledger wallet connected to my GUI wallet. I keep getting this error message:

```
Error 
Can't create transaction: unexpected error: unable to send Hidapi command. 
Error 64:hid_error is not implemented yet."
```

I have tried a number of different transactions to three different wallets, different sizes from 10 monero to a tiny amount. I even tried a new USB cable. Nothing has worked. What is going on here? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.reddit.com/r/monerosupport/comments/kx8o1v/cant_send_xmr_using_ledger/gjcwc6f/:

> The issue is fixed now. I followed these steps:
>
> 1. wait until both wallet & daemon are fully synchronized
> 2. close gui wallet
> 3. reboot mac os
> 4. open monero app on ledger
> 5. open gui wallet
> 6. export view key? -> yes
> 7. sent transaction succesfully